# как сделать setValue в useState был синхронным?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

В функции onFromSubmit есть функция validateForm, которая при помощи хука useState устанавливает состояние валидации (true/false), но делает она это асинхронно, и после выполнения этой функции следующий код не получает нового значения, оно остается старым. Значение меняется только после выполнения onFormSubmit. Как это исправить / обойти?

```js
import { addTodo } from "../../core/slices/todosSlice";
import { useAppDispatch} from "../../core/store/hooks";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import useInput from "../../core/hooks/useInput";
import "./addTodoPanel.scss"
import { useValidateInput } from "../../core/hooks/useValidate";

type AddTodoPanelProps = {
    readonly date: number
}

const AddTodoPanel: FC<AddTodoPanelProps> = ({date}) => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const [title, inputHandler, resetTitle] = useInput();
    const [titleValid, validateTitle, titleStatus] = useValidateInput({minLength: 5, maxLength: 100});
    const [descr, textareaHandler, resetDescr] = useInput();
    const [descrValid, validateDescr, descrStatus] = useValidateInput({minLength: 10});
    
    const resetForm = (): void => {
        resetTitle(); resetDescr();
    }

    const validateForm = (): void => {
        // setTitleValid false or true
        validateTitle(title); 
        // setDescrValid false or true
        validateDescr(descr);
        
    }

    const onFormSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
           
        validateForm();
        // тут должно поменяться значение validTitle и validDescr
        // но оно меняется только после завершения функции onFormSybmit
        // в titleValid и descrValid остается старое значение
        if (!titleValid  || !descrValid) {
            return;
        }        

        const todo = { title, descr, id: uuidv4(), time: 2020 }
        dispatch(addTodo({ todo, date }))

        resetForm();
    }

    return (
        <form className="add-todo__form" onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
            <FormItemLayout label="title" isValid={titleValid} errorMessage={titleStatus}>
                <input className="add-todo__input" onChange={inputHandler} value={title}/>    
            </FormItemLayout>
            <FormItemLayout label="description" isValid={descrValid} errorMessage={descrStatus}>
                <textarea className="add-todo__textarea" onChange={textareaHandler} value={descr}></textarea>
            </FormItemLayout>
            <button className="add-todo__button" type="submit">Add todo</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

хук useValidateInput:

```js
import { useState } from "react"

type UseValidateProps = {
    readonly minLength: number,
    readonly maxLength?: number | null
}

export const enum UseValidateStatus {
    confirm = 'confirm',
    strLengthOutOfRangeException = 'str length out of range exception',
    strLengthLessThenMinLength = 'str length less then min length'
}

type UseValidateInputReturn = [
    boolean,
    (str: string) => void,
    UseValidateStatus
]

export const useValidateInput = ({
    minLength = 20,
    maxLength = null
}: UseValidateProps): UseValidateInputReturn => {
    const [isValid, setIsValid ] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState<UseValidateStatus>(UseValidateStatus.confirm); 
    
    const validateValue = (str: string): void => {
        if (maxLength) {
            if (str.length > maxLength) {
                setIsValid(isValid => false);
                setStatus(UseValidateStatus.strLengthOutOfRangeException);
            } else {
                setIsValid(isValid => true);
                setStatus(UseValidateStatus.confirm);
            }
        }

        if (str.length < minLength) {
            setIsValid(isValid => false);
            setStatus(UseValidateStatus.strLengthLessThenMinLength);
        } else {
            setIsValid(isValid => true);
            setStatus(UseValidateStatus.confirm);
        }
    }

    return [isValid, validateValue, status]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А зачем вам валидация через стейты?

Comment: должно быть логическое значение, которое показывает валидна ли форма. Как вы предлагаете сделать по другому?

Comment: а зачем стейты? если нужно просто провалидировать значения? обычная функция валидации. причём тут стейты?